# Is the Laplace transform additive? And why?

Tags: laplace-transform

The first part is a simple question, but I cant find a clear answer.

Does:

$$\mathcal{L}(ax''(t)) = \mathcal{L}(a)\times\mathcal{L}(x''(t))$$

$a$ is a constant

$x(t)$ is a variable that changes with t

so

$$\mathcal{L}(a) = \frac{a}{s}$$
$$\mathcal{L}(x''(t))= s^2X(s)-sx(0)-x'(0)$$
$$\mathcal{L}(ax''(t)) = asX(s)-ax(0)-\frac{ax'(0)}{s}$$

Is this correct?

The alternative is that:

$$\mathcal{L}(ax''(t)) = a\times\mathcal{L}(x''(t))$$

so

$$\mathcal{L}(ax''(t)) = as^2X(s)-asx(0)-ax'(0)$$

If the latter is correct, why does the $a$ not get *"laplaced"*? The laplace transform of a constant number is that number divided by $s$, so why would the $a$ not get *"laplaced"* when it is multiplied by the variable $x(t)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, formally by [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Formal_definition): $\displaystyle\mathcal{L}_t\left\{f(t)\right\}=\int_0^{\infty} e^{-st} f(t) \,dt $, then (since $a$ is constant) $$\displaystyle\mathcal{L}_t\left\{a \ f(t)\right\}=\int_0^{\infty} e^{-st} (a \ f(t)) \,dt= a\int_0^{\infty} e^{-st}f(t) \,dt=a \ \displaystyle\mathcal{L}_t\left\{f(t)\right\}.$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I suppose the math makes sense; you can just take the _a_ outside of the integral, therefore you can take it outside the laplace. It just seemed strange to me at first not applying the laplace transform to the constant, because if the constant was added to function instead of multiplied then you would.